# Designing a database of Recipes

Tags: database-design

**Task**

I need database design to record Recipes.

- Recipes can contain several Ingredients and several ordered HowToSteps.
- Each HowToStep can be split into ordered HowToSections.
- A single recipe can contain a mix of several (ordered) HowToStep and (ordered) HowToSection elements.

**My Solution**

- Table `HowToSection` with FK to the table `HowToStep` with FK to the table `Recipe`.
- Table `Ingredient` with FK to the table `Recipe`.

**Issue**

I have no idea how to handle a business rule which stipulates that

- "A single recipe can contain a mix of several (ordered) HowToStep and (ordered) HowToSection elements".

Comment: Weird... sounds like a university assignment question.......................

Comment: Not your question, but you'll be bumping into it later.  The relationship between ingredients and recipes in many-to-many.  One recipe has many ingredients,  but an ingredient, like chopped garlic can go into many recipes.  Learn how to design for this case,  using a third intermediate table.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have a:

`RecipeSteps` table containing, `recipe_id`, `stepnumber` for order, and a `HowToStep` ref

And:

`RecipeSections` table containing, `recipe_id`, `sectionnumber` for order, and a `HowToSection` ref

The `stepnumber` and `sectionnumber` need to be non overlapping (per `recipe_id` for the pulling in the steps/sections in an order.